# Export Oracle table in PDF

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Oracle table with over 1 million records. I have to print all the records with header in a PDF.

How can this be achieved using PL/SQL?

Comment: Refer the Link : http://www.plpdf.com/

Comment: PDF is a proprietary file storage format. Oracle does not natively support external file formats. So you will need to have one of more intermediary steps, outside the database, or you will need to install a third-party product.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather to use SQLPlus reporting functionality to generate text/html report on the client side, but there is a PL/SQL package that lets you generate PDF file on the server.
Here is the project page on github https://github.com/Pilooz/pl_fpdf

Comment: Can SQLPlus generate PDF?

Comment: As I already mentioned you can generate reports in text or html using SQLPlus, here is documentation for that https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch7.htm

Comment: Anyway, I'm not going to say if generating a pdf/report is good for 1 milion records or not, but out of curiosity assuming 60 rows per page how useful is a pdf with 16,000+ pages?

Comment: It is for compliance. We need to maintain printable PDFs of records every day, which can then be destroyed after a year.

Comment: The person form Compliance who specified this should be made to print and read its output every day until they realise what a stupid, pointless requirement this is. No doubt there is a real business need underlying it but they should have specified it as a requirement - *we need to retain a daily snapshot of the data of the whatever table for a year* - rather than solutionizing.

Comment: Well, you cannot argue with compliance, they are indeed a pain.